# Best way to switch between material ui's accordion and tabs as a responsive tactic?

Tags: reactjs, tabs, material-ui, accordion

I want to switch between accordion and tabs, depending on the screen width using material UI react implementation (MUI). Is this possible? The documentation doesn't seem to cover this use case, but I would have thought it would be quite common.

I'm currently doing this, which renders an editorJs content block from my CMS very nicely in the accordion, but not sure how to get this to go to a tab layout when, say, screen width is > 768.

Any help appreciated.

```
        <Accordion>
            {data.listAccordions.data.length > 0
                ? data.listAccordions.data
                      .sort((a, b) =>
                          parseInt(a.priority) < parseInt(b.priority) ? 1 : -1
                      )
                      .map((accordionItem, index) => {
                          return (
                              <AccordionItem
                                  title={accordionItem.heading}
                                  icon={<EmptyIcon />}
                                  key={index}
                              >
                                  <div>
                                      <EditorRendererProvider
                                          data={{ blocks: accordionItem.content }}
                                      />
                                  </div>
                              </AccordionItem>
                          );
                      })
                : null}
        </Accordion>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically use two separate components; one for below the breakpoint and one for above the breakpoint. And a media query hook; there are many online.

```
const isLargeScreen = useMedia('(min-width: 768px)');

return isLargeScreen ? <Tabs items={myItems} /> : <Accordion items={myItems} />;
```

here is one hook implementation you could use:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export const useMedia = (query: any) => {
  const [matches, setMatches] = useState(window.matchMedia(query).matches);

  useEffect(() => {
    const media = window.matchMedia(query);
    if (media.matches !== matches) setMatches(media.matches);
    const listener = () => setMatches(media.matches);
    media.addListener(listener);
    return () => media.removeListener(listener);
  }, [matches, query]);

  return matches;
};
```

Comment: Aaah. Of course. I was overthinking it. Thank you :)

Comment: Oh - one thing. This will be server-side rendered - I *think* the useState would bork due to the absence of window? Afaik you can't conditionally call hooks - how would you deal with that? Could I just set the state variable to null? The useEffect will be ignored by SSR renderer so the window magic there would be ok, I think.

Comment: I have no experience with SSR. Are you full SSR or mixed (React Server Components)? In case you are full SSR: you can render both components into the DOM and switch their root node visibility via CSS media query

Comment: But I really don't know what the SSR best practices are for responsive.

Comment: Ok great Thanks for your help. I've dropped the SSR requirement for now :)